# Outlook 2013 not searching in new contacts

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search, microsoft-outlook-2013

When I want to search info at the "Notes" field of Contacts in Outlook 2013 of NEW contacts (I mean contacts of the last days) I got the message of not finding it.
When I look for info of previous contacts it works ok.
Indexing status says that all my items are indexed.
I close and open the program. Reboot machine. Problem persists.

Comment: So when you search for information contained in existing contacts the information is located and when you search for information for brand new contacts the information is not located?  Is that correct?

Comment: Try and rebuild the index.  This option is located within the `Indexing Options`

Comment: Exactly! I'm positive it is already there!

Comment: I rebuilt the index and the problem remains!!

Comment: But I don't have the problem in safe mode